# Return comma-separated list from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure as below. Now I want to modify it so that it returns the value as a comma separated list.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CUST_Notification_GetCompaniesFromEmails]
     @EmailValue AS NTEXT
AS
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         ISNULL(CompanyAddressesContacts.FirstName, '') + ' ' +  
         ISNULL(CompanyAddressesContacts.LastName, '') AS ContactName
         ,ISNULL(dbo.Companies.CompanyName,'') AS CompanyName,
         CASE
            WHEN CompanyName = 'Meraas Development' THEN '1'
            WHEN CompanyName = 'Samsung C&T' THEN '2'
            ELSE '3'
         END AS id
     FROM 
         dbo.CompanyAddressesContacts
     INNER JOIN 
         dbo.Companies ON dbo.CompanyAddressesContacts.CompanyId = Companies.Id
     WHERE 
         dbo.CompanyAddressesContacts.Email IN 
            (SELECT [value] 
             FROM dbo.SplitWords(@EmailValue,';'))
```

The above code returns values as a normal select statement would do . Now I want a modification in the code so that it returns a value as comma-separated list.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this procedure ever return more than 1 row? The `DISTINCT` makes me suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') + CAST(OfferID AS VARCHAR)
FROM   Emp
WHERE  EmpID = 23

SELECT @List
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SplitWords` method as

`dbo.SplitWords(@EmailValue +',','')`

Have a visit

http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2007/04/08/coalesce-is-not-the-answer-to-string-concatentation-in-t-sql.aspx

http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2011/11/sql-server-convert-table-column-data.html